# How to Increase the time till a read timeout error occurs?

Tags: php, firefox, zend-framework, timeout

I've written in PHP a script that takes a long time to execute [Image processing for thousands of pictures]. It's a meter of hours - maybe 5.

After 15 minutes of processing, I get the error:

---

ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: *The URL which I clicked*

```
Read Timeout
```

The system returned: [No Error]

A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

---

What I need is to enable that script to run for much longer.

Now, here are all the technical info:
I'm writing in PHP and using the Zend Framework. I'm using Firefox. The long script that is processed is done after clicking a link. Obviously, since the script is not over I see the web page on which the link was and the web browser writes "waiting for ...".
After 15 minutes the error occurs.

I tried to make changes to Firefox threw about:config but without any success. I don't know, but the changes might be needed somewhere else.

So, any ideas?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the process runs for hours then you should probably look into batch processing. So you just store a request for image processing (in a file, database or whatever works for you) instead of starting the image processing. This request is then picked up by a scheduled (cron) process running on the server, which will do the actual processing (this can be a PHP script, which calls set_time_limit(0)). And when processing is finished you could signal the user (by mail or any other way that works for you) that the processing is finished.

Answer (score 1):

set_time_limit(0) will only affect the server-side running of the script. The error you're receiving is purely browser-side. You have to send SOMETHING to keep the browser from deciding the connection's dead - even a single character of output (followed by a `flush()` to make sure it actually get sent out over the wire) will do. Maybe once every image that's processed, or on a fixed time interval (`if last char sent more than 5 minutes ago, output another one`).

If you don't want any intermediate output, you could do `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)`, which will allow the script to keep running even if the connection gets shut down from the client side.

Comment: I tried to write a "." every minute, and it indeed wrote it though the script was still running. 
But after 15 minutes the script stopped, and I was left with a page with nothing but 15 dots. I tried using ignore_user_abort(TRUE), but it didn't make any difference. The script still didn't finish.

Comment: Could be the browser wants more than just 15 bytes to consider the connection open. Odd that the script stopped after the 15 minutes with the ignore_user_abort(). Are you sure there isn't something else shutting it down? Perhaps a max-cpu ulimit?

Answer (score 0):

use set_time_limit

documentation here

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I tried writing set_time_limit(0) and set_time_limit(999999) before the long script, but there was no success. I still got the error after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can split your work in batches, after processing X images display the page with some javascript (or META redirects) on it to open the link http://server/controller/action/nextbatch/next_batch_id.

Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

batching the entire process also has the added benefit that once something goes wrong, you don't have to start out the entire thing anew.

If you're running on a server of your own and can get out of safe_mode, then you could also fork background processes to do the actual heavy lifting, independent of your browser view of things.  If you're in a multicore or multiprocessor environment, you can even schedule more than one running process at any time.

We've done something like that for large computation scripts; synchronization of the processes happened over a shared database---but luckily enough, they processes were so independent that the only thing we needed to see was their completion or termination.